# How can I separate these xml elements?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I got an xml response of

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [version] => 2.0
            [msg_type] => response
        )

    [header] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [param] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => SN
                                    [value] => 1012
                                )

                        )


    ...

                    [9] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => ErrorInfo
                                    [value] => NA
                                )

                        )

                    [10] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => ProcessTime
                                    [value] => 0
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [Heartbeat] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

)
```

I tried:

```
$version1 = (string) $xml->version; // expecting to get "2.0"
$errorinfo = (string) $xml->name->ErrorInfo; // expecting to get "NA"
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: It looks like the response from PHP SimpleXML.

Comment: Should be something like [`$xml->attributes()->version`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php).

Comment: Yes, it is php. Passerby, with your line I can get the "version" now. However, I still fail to get the next value SN. I tried $SN_r = (string) $xml->header->param->attributes()->SN;

Comment: post the XML instead of that var_dump. XML's advantage is that it is human readable...